# Removing markup when working with enlive

Tags: clojure, web-scraping

I'm learning to use the fantastic enlive library to do some web-scraping. I need to capture some text that may be partially highlighted. For example the html may look like:

```
<a href="example.com" class="usefulLink"><font color="#CC0000">Foo</font> <font color="#CC0000">Bar</font> <font color="#CC0000">Baz</font> <font color="#CC0000">Blah</font>rest of text</a>
```

The result when using (select page [:a.usefulLink]) is a lot of `{:tag :font :attrs {...} :content {...}}`

My question is: is there an easy way to just fish out the :content stuff without all the other unnecessary stuff, or do I need to do it myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `unwrap`.

```
(-> page
  (select [:a.usefulLink])
  (at [:font] unwrap))
```